# Flutter: Add element in class A from class B

Tags: list, flutter, oop, dart

I am looking to add an item to a list within class `A` from class `B`.

Using a button in class `B`

```
IconButton(
  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
  onPressed: () {
    print(element.tag);
    FirstScreenState().elementList.add(element.tag);
  }
)
```

I try to add the element to the list in class `A`

```
class FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  List<String> elementList = List<String>();
}
```

But when it tried to print the list, it prints an empty list. Why?

```
flutter: []
```

Comment: Your question is missing information and context. Are Class A and Class B related in any way? You can't simply instantiate a Widget and call a method from it as if it was a singleton. If Class B is next in the navigation stack, after Class A, then you can just pass the method as part of Class B's constructor.

Comment: Yes, class A precedes class B in navigation, class A is a screen made using the information that class B collects from the user, I cannot send the information through the constructor because it does not collect information from the user only once and each time I do it, the class is rebuilt and the previous information disappears

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to use Global  key

first, define final GlobalKey

```
<your list> _key = GlobalKey();
```

then in onPressed funtion use

```
_key.currentState.setTodo(Todo(title: _textFieldController.text));
```

after that add key to class

```
class yourClass extends StatefulWidget {
  yourClass({Key key}) : super(key: key);
```

finally, pass the key

```
body: yourClass (
        key: _key,
      ),
```

for more details reffer this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58516496/10120299)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that has both the method from Class A being called in Class B from simply passing the method in the constructor from A to B, and also Class A calling a method from Class B using the GlobalKey. It is important to observe that the GlobalKey is declared with the type of the state class of Class B:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<_ClassBState> classBKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ClassA(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ClassA extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<_ClassBState> classBKey = GlobalKey();

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.blueGrey,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Class A'),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Class B method'),
            onPressed: () => classBKey.currentState.methodInBClass(),
          ),
          ClassB(
            callback: methodInClassA,
            key: classBKey,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void methodInClassA(){
    print('methodInClassA');
  }
}

class ClassB extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function callback;

  ClassB({
    Key key,
    this.callback,
  }) : super(key: key) ;

  @override
  _ClassBState createState() => _ClassBState();
}

class _ClassBState extends State<ClassB> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.amber,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Class B'),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Class A method'),
            onPressed: () => widget.callback(),
          ),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }

  void methodInBClass(){
    print('methodInBClass');
  }
}
```

If you would like me to separate each concept individually, I can change the code.

Comment: thanks for the answer, when trying to implement your solution it returns me `The method 'addElement' was called on null.`. Both classes are `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: You have shared the `addElement` method you mention in your code. I can't help you with that. Also, you explanation as to why you can't pass the method in the constructor is very confusing " I cannot send the information through the constructor because it does not collect information from the user only once and each time I do it" because it does not collect information?

Comment: I want to fill a list declared in `class A` element by element through a function of `class B`, after adding an element through the `addElement` function I go back to the previous screen (`class A`) and start the process again but the data is not preserved, both are `statefulWidget`